# powershell that loops in folder to change the remote url

Tags: git, powershell

I am trying to create a script that changes the "remote origin URL" of a git config file in Powershell

```
# Set the parent directory containing all the Git repositories 
$parentDirectory = "C:\tmp\ReposMainFolder" 
# Define the old url for remote repository 
$oldUrl = "https://xxxxx" 
# Define the new url for remote repository 
$newUrl = "https://yyyyyy"
# Get all subdirectories (Git repositories) within the parent directory 
$gitRepos = Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -Match ".git" } | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } 
  Write-Host "gitRepos: $gitRepos"

 

    foreach ($gitRepo in $gitRepos) { $repoPath = $gitRepo 
    Set-Location -Path $repoPath 
    Write-Host "Processing repository: $repoPath" 
    Write-Host "Current remote URL:" git remote get-url origin 
   $newRemoteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the new remote URL" 
    $configPath = Join-Path -Path $repoPath -ChildPath ".git\config" 
    $configContent = Get-Content -Path $configPath 
    $configContent = $configContent -replace '(?ms)(\[remote "origin"\].*?url = ").*?(".*$)', "`$1$newRemoteUrl`$2" 
    Set-Content -Path $configPath -Value $configContent
      Write-Host "Updated remote URL:" git remote get-url origin 
      Write-Host "========================================="}
```

what I see is that the gitRepos log is empty.
I made attempts replacing the `-Match` with `-Like` without success.
I have also tried without `-Recurse`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `$gitRepos = (Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Filter '.git' -Directory -Recurse).FullName`. Question: what is `clea` ??

Comment: An update is that when I try `$gitRepos = Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Directory -Recurse 
  Write-Host "gitRepos: $gitRepos"` in the gitRepos the .git folders are not present and I am guessing it happens this because they are hidden

Comment: If you think the .git folders are hidden, append switch `-Force` to the Get-ChildItem line, so it becomes `$gitRepos = (Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Filter '.git' -Directory -Recurse -Force).FullName`. And also add `-Force` to the Get-Content line. P.S. you didn't say what `clea` should mean. Possibly switch `-Raw` ?

Comment: yes it is still empty

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, because **`.git` directories are *hidden*** (have the `Hidden` file attribute on Windows)<sup>[1]</sup>, they are **by default *excluded*** from being listed among the child / descendant items via [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):
**`-Force` must be used to include hidden files and directories.**

- The exact rules when `-Force` is needed are complex and vary across cmdlets, and summarized in [GitHub issue #6473](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6473#issuecomment-375930843), with existing *inconsistencies* / *missing functionality* being tracked in [GitHub issue #6501](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6501) and [GitHub issue #6502](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6502)

---

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) points out, the more robust and efficient way to formulate your command is as follows:

```bash
$gitRepos = 
  Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Force -Recurse -Directory -Filter .git |
  ForEach-Object FullName
```

Note the use of the `-Filter` parameter, which filters *at the source* (with support for wildcard expressions as used by the native file-system APIs) and is therefore much faster than filtering *after the fact*.
Also note the use of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) to extract the `.FullName` property.

---

Taking a step back: Since you ultimately want to iterate over the `config` files located inside all `.git` directories in the subtree of `$parentPath`, you can locate and process them directly with the following pipeline:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Force -Recurse -File -Filter config |
  Where-Object { $_.Directory.Name -eq '.git' } |
  ForEach-Object {
     # Work with $_ here - it represents a 'config' file of interest.
     $configContent = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
     # ...
  }
```

Note the use of `-File` and `-Filter config`, and the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call to ensure that the parent directory is indeed a `.git` directory.

---

<sup>[1] On *Unix*-like platforms, it is *a name starting with `.`*  that makes a file or directory hidden. On *Windows*, it is solely the `Hidden` attribute, irrespective of the name.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

it need it a `-Force` to get the hidden files

```
$gitRepos = Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Directory -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.FullName -Match ".git" } | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: `-match` uses regex, so if you want to filter on the extension you need to **anchor** it to the end PLUS the dot means _Any Character_ so you'll have to escape that with a backslash if you don't want it to pass 'Agit' or 'Xgit' anywhere in the directory name.. In this case, you don't need regex, so using  `-Filter '.git'` is the better choice because it is also a lot faster than testing the name afterwards